# DatePicker throws an exception for Visibility

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, caliburn.micro, windows-phone-toolkit

I've added a DatePicker in own of my views, and I get an error for the Visibility property (which I have not configured).

The error is:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 'MS.Internal.Data.DynamicValueConverter' converter failed to convert value '8/18/1993' (type 'System.String'); BindingExpression: Path='DateOfBirth' DataItem='Gui.ViewModels.RegisterPersonalViewModel' (HashCode=64515557); target element is 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.DatePicker' (Name='DateOfBirth'); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'System.Windows.Visibility').. System.ArgumentException: Requested value '8/18/1993' was not found.
   at System.Enum.EnumResult.SetFailure(ParseFailureKind failure, String failureMessageID, Object failureMessageFormatArgument)
   at System.Enum.TryParseEnum(Type enumType, String value, Boolean ignoreCase, EnumResult& parseResult)
   at System.Enum.Parse(Type enumType, String value, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at MS.Internal.SilverlightTypeConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
   at MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.ConvertHelper(Object o, Type destinationType, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isForward)
   at MS.Internal.Data.TargetDefaultValueConverter.Convert(Object o, Type type, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   at MS.Internal.Data.DynamicValueConverter.Convert(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ConvertToTarget(Object value).
```

The view field looks like:

```
<toolkit:DatePicker x:Name="DateOfBirth" />
```

And the property in the view model:

```
public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

Hence I have nothing which maps the Visibility property to the field. So why do it make that binding?

I also tried to add a visibility binding like this:

```
<toolkit:DatePicker x:Name="DateOfBirth"
                       Visibility="{Binding Path=IsDateOfBirthVisible,
                                    Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

And add a field:

```
public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
public bool IsDateOfBirthVisible { get; set; }
```

But then I get the following exception:

> An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary

I've also tried to add custom conventions:

```
ConventionManager.AddElementConvention<DatePicker>(DateTimePickerBase.ValueProperty, "Value", "SelectedDate");
ConventionManager.AddElementConvention<DatePicker>(DateTimePickerBase.ValueStringFormatProperty, "ValueStringFormat", "ValueStringFormatChanged");
ConventionManager.AddElementConvention<DatePicker>(DateTimePickerBase.ValueStringProperty, "ValueString", "ValueStringChanged");
ConventionManager.AddElementConvention<DatePicker>(UIElement.VisibilityProperty, "Visibility", "VisibilityChanged");
```

But that doesn't make a difference.

I'm new both to caliburn and windows phone, so there might be a stupid mistake somewhere.

How do I get rid of that exception?

*(the datepicker is from https://phone.codeplex.com/)*

Comment: from the error is seems that the binding for visibility is to the date item and not to boolean item,  BindingExpression: Path='DateOfBirth' DataItem='Gui.ViewModels.RegisterPersonalViewModel' (HashCode=64515557); target element is 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.DatePicker' (Name='DateOfBirth'); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'System.Windows.Visibility').. System.ArgumentException: Requested value '8/18/1993' was not found.

Comment: @bjoshi: But why do it try to use that for the Visibility?

Comment: This is weird. Have you tried removing the `x:Name` property to see if the problem still exists, I mean not lean CM configure the binding automatically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caliburn.Micro has a "catch all" convention definied on the `FrameworkElement` which binds your matching property on the viewmodel to the `FrameworkElement.VisibilityProperty`

```
AddElementConvention<FrameworkElement>(
    FrameworkElement.VisibilityProperty, "DataContext", "Loaded");
```

Because Caliburn.Micro does not know about the `Microsoft.Phone.Controls.DatePicker` type or its base classes (`DateTimePickerBase`, `Control`) it fallbacks to the `FrameworkElement` convention and it tries to bind your `DateTime` to the `DatePicker` `VisibilityProperty` so you see the exception in the Output window.

There are two solutions:

- Write the binding by hand: `<toolkit:DatePicker Value="{Bidning DateOfBirth}" />`
- Create a custom convention, which is in this case:

  ```
  ConventionManager.AddElementConvention<DatePicker>(
       DateTimePickerBase.ValueProperty, "Value", "SelectedDate");
  ```

  Note: you can only have one convetion for a given type, so this should be your **only** `AddElementConvention<DatePicker>` call.